# How to allow line breaks / empty lines in jslint

Tags: javascript, jslint

I want to allow line breaks in jslint. Now I have to do it like this:

```
function foo(){
    //...
}
function bar(){
    //...
}
```

I wonder why jslint forces me to do it this way. What I want is something like:

```
function foo(){
    // ...
}

// any number of empty lines for better readability

function bar(){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What is the warning that you get?

Comment: I get "unexpected character '(space)'"

Comment: Add `/*jslint: white:true */` to the top of the file. Some JSLint tools allow you to set this permanently from within the tool, though the "raw" source expects one file at a time. That said, what you've got that "works" should be producing `Expected one space between ')' and '{'.` without a `white` directive.